# complete an incomplete type for a wrapper in C

Tags: c, wrapper, typedef

I stayed stuck on this problem a good part of the day.
My goal is to link two libraries. I can only touch to wrapper.c/.h and DepB.h files.
I'm trying to get library A using one of his structure (structA) holded by library B struct (structB).
I know that i could store structA as a void* in structB then cast it, but I'd like to get more sexy code without!

[image]

Actually, gcc return me following errors for wrap():

```
void wrap (structB* structBptr)
{
  structA structAinst;
  structBptr->structAptr = &structAinst;
  //  warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
  
  funcA(structBptr->structAptr->someField);
  //  error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'struct structA'
}
```

I wonder if this problem come from DepA.h defining structA as a type...
What can i write in my wrapper or in LibB dependencies that he take DepA.h definition of structA?

Comment: You need to include `DepB.h` either in your `wrapper.c` file or in `wrapper.h`.

Comment: Oups i forgot to put it on my scheme, it is included in my actual project!
I updated picture!

Comment: You do not have a `struct structA` anywhere. You need a struct tag in declaration of `structA`.

Comment: There is a typedef in DepA.h:
typedef struct {...} structA;

Comment: `struct structA` is not the same as `structA`.

Comment: mh Ok, that's what i was struggling with.
I succeed passing incomplete types by changing structA defintion to:

`struct structA{...};
typedef struct structA structA;`

But knowing i can't modify DepA.h, is there a way to get it working?

Comment: Can you include `DepA.h` inside `DepB.h`? Then just change `struct structA* structAptr;` to `structA* structAptr;`

Comment: It should work but i want the two libraries to be as separated as possible (i'm facing maccro and types redefinition).
I found a solution pretty similar from what you answered, by creating a wrapper type.

Answer (score 0):

A solution was to create a wrapper type:
[image]

With this solution, structA is still unknown from libraryB.

Comment: If you want to be transparent for LibB, you could just use a `void*` in the struct declarations and only cast to the real type inside the functions in wrapper.c

Comment: I want to be transparent, but force layers called by wrapper to initialise libB with correct types.
A cast will remove warnings if a bad typed pointer is set.
Is there something you don't like in this solution?